# how to check type/interface compatibility?

Tags: typescript

I want to create an interface with rules that other interfaces can follow or implement,

here an example:

```js
interface GeneralTheme {
  [topic: string]: string;
}

/* now if I want a specific version of this I would do something like this 
(here I'd like something like "implements" instead of "extends"): */

interface SpecificCorrectTheme extends GeneralTheme {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;
}

/* and if I make a mistake with the implementation TS should mark it as wrong, 
which TS actually does, so TS works really well for this case */

interface SpecificWrongTheme extends GeneralTheme {
  key1: string;
  key2: { nestedKey: string };
}

/* so far so good, the problem comes when I want to make use of the 
specificity of the SpecificCorrectTheme like: */

type SpecificThemeKey = keyof SpecificCorrectTheme;

/* I would like SpecificThemeKey to be 'key1' | 'key2', but instead 
it accepts any string, which tells me that the interface SpecificCorrectTheme 
is pretty much equal to GeneralTheme which makes it useless

Note that none of this has anything to do with runtime checking 
so I'm not looking for custom type guards */
```

So how can I have both benefits (recognizing base interface implementation errors while keeping specific characteristics) or another way to guarantee this compatibility between the GeneralTheme and the SpecificTheme interfaces, is there a way to do this in typescript (without classes, I know they support interface implementation)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to do it with generics, if anyone knows a better solution please post it

```js
// we have the general interface
interface GeneralTheme {
  [topic: string]: string;
}

// we need to create a checker that receives the type to be checked
type GeneralThemeChecker<T extends GeneralTheme> = T

// then we just pass the desired implementation to the checker, 
// if it extends (or is compatible with) the general interface it will return the same type
type SpecificCorrectTheme = GeneralThemeChecker< {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;
}>

// otherwise the linter will mark it as an error
type SpecificWrongTheme = GeneralThemeChecker <{
  key1: string;
  key2: { nestedKey: string };
}>

// and the type specifics are maintained as this returns "key1" | "key2"
type SpecificThemeKey = keyof SpecificCorrectTheme;

// and the specific type is compatible for reassignment as desired
const specific: SpecificCorrectTheme = {
  key1: 'val1',
  key2: 'val2'
}

const general: GeneralTheme = specific
```

:)